# How can enable the filter on managed metadata fields on REST API direct?

Tags: rest, api, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx

How can enable the filter on managed metadata fields label on REST API direct and fetch all the fields using the filtering of the MMS field using direct REST API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same situation on this i have enable the filtering using the Managed Metadata fields on a list using the below API:

```
_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('List-name')/Items/?$select=*,TaxCatchAll/Term&$filter=TaxCatchAll/Term eq '${Managed-Metadata-field-value}'&$expand=TaxCatchAll
```

> 'Managed-Metadata-field-value' means: Country is the MMS field and US is the value put US on here

But the API have limitation i think this filter enable only on a single MMS field.

Refer:[workaround-to-filter-on-taxonomy](https://www.techmikael.com/2016/05/workaround-to-filter-on-taxonomy.html)

Answer (score 0):

its not possible out of the box, but there are some workarounds for this.

See: http://www.cleverworkarounds.com/2013/09/23/how-to-filter-on-a-managed-metadata-column-via-rest-in-sharepoint-2013/